# Adjust font size of the street labels in here maps

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, here-api

We have been working on this for quite some time now. But still, just to confirm, is there a way we can increase the font size of the street labels in heremaps? We know that we can customize marker font styles using:

```
iconMarkup      = '<svg style="left:-{{{LEFT}}}px;top:-{{{TOP}}}px;"' 
                                + 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="{{{WIDTH}}}px" height="{{{HEIGHT}}}px" >'
                                + '<g transform="scale({{{SCALE}}})"><path d="M 19 31 C 19 32.7 16.3 34 13 34 C 9.7 34 7 32.7 7 31 C 7 29.3 9.7 ' 
                                + '28 13 28 C 16.3 28 19 29.3 19 31 Z" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".2"></path>'
                                + '<path d="M 13 0 C 9.5 0 6.3 1.3 3.8 3.8 C 1.4 7.8 0 9.4 0 12.8 C 0 16.3 1.4 ' 
                                + '19.5 3.8 21.9 L 13 31 L 22.2 21.9 C 24.6 19.5 25.9 16.3 25.9 12.8 C 25.9 9.4 24.6 ' 
                                + '6.1 22.1 3.8 C 19.7 1.3 16.5 0 13 0 Z" fill="#fff"></path>'
                                + '<path d="M 13 2.2 C 6 2.2 2.3 7.2 2.1 12.8 C 2.1 16.1 3.1 18.4 5.2 20.5 L '
                                + '13 28.2 L 20.8 20.5 C 22.9 18.4 23.8 16.2 23.8 12.8 C 23.6 7.07 20 2.2 ' 
                                + '13 2.2 Z" fill="{{{COLOUR}}}"></path>'
                                + '<text transform="matrix( 1 0 0 1 13 18 )" x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="1" '
                                + 'fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" '
                                + 'font-weight="bold" font-size="13px" font-family="arial">{{{REPLACE_TEXT}}}</text></g></svg>';
```

but still is there a way to increase the font size of the map street labels? It appears too small in the mobile devices as compared to their mobile sites.

[image]

as compared to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using by altering the pixel-points-per-inch using the `ppi` parameter from the [Map Tile API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/resource-base-maptile.html). You can set the base layer as shown:

```
function setBaseLayer(map, platform){
  var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
      type: 'base'
    });
  var parameters = {
      ppi: '250'};
  var tileLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'maptile',
      'normal.day',
      256,
      'png8',
      parameters
    );
  map.setBaseLayer(tileLayer);
}
```

The valid values are 72, 250 or 320. 250 is normally used for mobile.

Compare the following:

[image]

`normal.day` 72 ppi

[image]

`normal.day` 250 ppi

Alternatively use the `normal.day.mobile` schema rather than the standard `normal-day`

[image]

`normal.day.mobile` 72 ppi

Answer (score 0):

Just Adding on to the Answer posted by "Jason Fox" - It would be more effective on the mobile view by adding the **`normal.day.mobile`** instead of **`normal.day`**:

```
var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
                  type: 'base'
                });
              var parameters = {
                  ppi: '250'};
              var tileLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
                  'maptile',
                  'normal.day.mobile',
                  256,
                  'png8',
                  parameters
                );
              map.setBaseLayer(tileLayer);
```